# C++: using for loop to allow user input of numbers into array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, c++11, for-loop

I'm new to the community and to coding as well. Right now I'm taking Intro to Computer Science at my CC and we're learning C++. Anyways, I have to create a program which asks the user for a number, which will be the size indicator of the array `new_array`. The program then asks the user to input the numbers one by one and afterwards, outputs them in reverse. 
    #include 
    using namespace std;

```
int main()
{
cout << "How many numbers?\n";
int numbers; // holds amount of numbers to be entered into array
cin >> numbers;
int new_array[numbers];
for(int counter = 0; counter < numbers; counter++)
{
    cout << "Enter number " << counter << endl;
    cin >> new_array[counter];
}

cout << "You entered: " << endl;

for(int i = numbers; i >= 0 ; i-- )
{
    cout << new_array[i] << endl;

}

return 0;
}
```

I understand how to do this and for the most part, my program worked. It outputs the numbers entered in reverse just fine, but before it does so, it outputs large, strange numbers. For example, if the user enters `5` as the amount of numbers to be entered, and then enters `1, 2, 3, 4` and `6` as the `5` numbers respectively, the program outputs the number `4669476` first and then outputs the numbers in the array in reverse. Can anyone explain to me what I did wrong and how I could fix this? Thank you in advanced!
PS be gentle! I'm a newbie at this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This loop reads out of bounds:

```
for(int i = numbers; i >= 0 ; i-- )
{
```

If you follow `i` through in your head you will see that you output entries `numbers` through to `0`, when in fact you should output entries `numbers-1` through to `0`.

An alternative patterns is:

```
for( int i = numbers; i--; )
```

Or you can use the fabled [`-->` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator).

It would be possible to "simply" start from `numbers - 1`, however the loop pattern you have used would not work for an unsigned counter (because they are always `>= 0`). IMHO it is a good idea to use a pattern which works for all types; then you are less likely to make a mistake in future.

Answer (score 0):

In your display `for loop`, you started from `i = numbers` which is out of the array's range. Since the array starts from `0 till size - 1`, then you need to start from `i = numbers - 1` all the way to `>=0`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you start from `array[numbers]` which is not defined.

`array[0], array[1], ... array[numbers-1]` are defined.

Answer (score 0):

In C arrays are stored from 0 instead of 1. So the last number is stored in `array[4]`

So when you're writing it out you should start an `numbers - 1` instead of just `numbers`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are starting the index  from out of range giving  you garbage value.

your code should look some thing like this

```
 for(int i = numbers-1; i >= 0 ; i-- )
 {
     cout << new_array[i] << endl;
  }
```